# Как сделать анимацию вращения электронов вокруг ядра атома

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Как такое можно сделать на SVG?

Мне нужно, чтобы маленькие шарики (электроны) двигались хаотично по линиям вокруг ядра атома, а сама фигура в целом переливалась разными цветами.
 Как сделать такую анимацию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на svg можно и не такое сделать. Попробую..

Comment: спасибо вам!,,,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Основу для svg элемента лучше делать в векторном редакторе. Для этого необходимы совсем минимальные навыки.

Загружаете  картинку в векторный редактор:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="406" height="358" viewBox="0 0 406 358" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGVcB.png" width="406" height="358" />
</svg>
```

И инструментом  `Рисовать кривые Безье` (синяя стрелка на изображении) наносите по контурам картинки узловые точки (красные стрелки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняете файл в векторном редакторе и копируете необходимые `path` в другой svg файл

Ниже код приложения для понимания работы прочтите комментарии:

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#95006A;
 stroke-width:2;
}
.core {
fill:url(#Rg);
}

.circ {
fill:url(#Rg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="406" height="358" viewBox="0 0 406 358">
  <defs>
  <radialGradient id="Rg"  >
   <stop stop-color="#95006A" offset="0.25">
  <!-- Анимация смены цвета градиента -->
  <animate
    attributeName="stop-color"
 dur="4s"
 values="#95006A;#69009D;#95006A"
 begin="0s"
 
 repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
   </stop>
   <stop stop-color="#69009D" offset="1">
    <animate
  attributeName="stop-color"
  dur="2s"
  values="#69009D;#95006A;#69009D"
  begin="0s"
  
  repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
  
  </radialGradient>
 </defs> 
        <!-- Центральное ядро -->
  <path class="core" d="m203.8 139.7c8.9-0.2 18.6 2.7 25.2 8.6 7.5 6.7 12.9 17.3 12.9 27.4-0.1 11.1-6.1 22.7-14.5 30-6.2 5.4-15.4 8.2-23.6 7.5-10.9-0.9-22.9-5.5-29.2-14.7-4.6-6.6-8.7-14.5-8.6-22.5 0.2-9.4 4.2-19.5 11-26 6.9-6.6 17.3-10 26.8-10.2zM279 29.9" class="s0"/>
  <path id="orbita_1" d="m279 29.9c24 6.8 23.5 39.1 21.8 60.5-2.1 26.4-10.5 47.3-19.3 69.7-7.3 18.7-17.4 36.3-27.8 53.5-9 14.9-18.7 29.5-29.6 43.1-10.4 12.9-21 25.9-33.8 36.5-13 10.7-27 21.5-43.1 26.6-7.7 2.4-17 5.2-24.2 1.5-10.6-5.4-17.4-18.5-19.1-30.3-4.3-29.8 4.6-60.3 14.5-88.5 9.5-26.8 19.3-42.7 31.3-62.7 12.2-20.3 25.1-40.4 41-57.9 13.2-14.6 27.3-29.1 44.5-38.6 13.3-7.4 30.1-17.1 43.6-13.3z" class="s0"/> 
       <!-- Орбита вращения -->
  <path id="orbita_2" d="m40.5 175.3c0.9-16.1 16.2-30.3 30.4-37.5 13.2-6.6 27.2-11.4 41.3-15.7 12.2-3.7 24.6-6.8 37.2-8.7 14-2.2 28.3-2.8 42.5-3.4 10.6-0.5 21.2-0.6 31.9-0.4 11.4 0.2 22.8 0.2 34.1 1.5 11.2 1.3 22.4 3.5 33.4 6.1 9.6 2.2 19.3 4.3 28.4 8 13.1 5.2 27.4 9.9 37.5 19.7 6.1 5.9 11.2 13.7 12.5 22 1.1 6.8-0.5 14.3-4.2 20.1-7.5 11.6-21.2 17.8-33.4 24.3-9.5 5.1-20 8.2-30.3 11.3-13.9 4.2-28.1 7.7-42.5 9.9-15.8 2.4-31.8 3-47.8 3.4-12 0.3-24-0.2-36-0.8-11.8-0.6-23.6-0.7-35.3-2.7-17.5-2.9-34.9-7.1-51.6-13.3C78.6 215.4 67.6 212 59.5 204.8 50.8 197 39.9 187 40.5 175.3Z" class="s0"/>
  <path id="orbita_3" d="m119.8 34.9c7.9-4.7 18.2-5.7 27.3-4.3 10.1 1.5 19.1 7.7 27.6 13.3 9.5 6.2 17.8 14.2 25.9 22.1 7 6.8 13.5 14.1 19.6 21.6 11.1 13.6 21.6 27.7 30.9 42.6 7.1 11.4 12.8 23.6 18.8 35.6 4.7 9.4 9.8 18.7 13.7 28.4 5.6 14.1 10.6 28.4 13.7 43.2 3 14.2 4.8 28.8 4.6 43.4-0.1 6.7-0.4 13.7-2.7 20-2.2 5.9-5.2 12.1-10.1 15.9-5.5 4.2-12.8 6.4-19.7 6.5-9.6 0-18.9-4.3-27.4-8.8-10.9-5.8-20-14.6-29.1-22.9-9.5-8.6-18.5-17.9-26.6-27.9-12.4-15.4-22.9-32.2-33.3-49-6.8-11.1-13.5-22.2-19-34-6.2-13.2-11.1-27-15.5-40.8-3.9-12-7.9-24.1-9.9-36.6-1.9-11.8-2.7-23.9-1.9-35.8 0.5-6.7 1-13.7 3.8-19.9 2.1-4.8 5-9.8 9.5-12.5z" class="s0"/>  
      <!-- Анимация вращения  электрона -1 вокруг ядра   -->
  <circle class="circ" cx="0" cy="0" r="10"  > 
      <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_1"/>
   </animateMotion>    
        
   </circle>  
     <!-- Анимация вращения  электрона -2 вокруг ядра   -->
     <circle class="circ" cx="0" cy="0" r="10"  > 
       <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_2"/>
       </animateMotion>    
    </circle>    
    <!-- Анимация вращения  электрона -3 вокруг ядра   -->
    <circle class="circ" cx="0" cy="0" r="10"  > 
       <animateMotion dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_3"/>
       </animateMotion>    
    </circle>  
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Скажите, а каким векторным редактором лучше пользоваться? Каким вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @Владислав Да не за что. Я пользуюсь Inkscape, вполне хватает для этих целей. Чтобы закрепить материал, попробуйте повторить весь процесс с другой фигурой Чтобы точно получилось пиксель в пиксель устанавливайте размеры svg равными размерам картинки

Comment: Это же вроде эллипсы, а ты их по точкам рисуешь...

Comment: @Qwertiy тут есть нюансы: Трансформации svg и css конфликтуют плюс ещё когда накладывается анимация. Поэтому не всё так просто. Конечно же я помню про эллипсы :)))) В этом конкретном случае не проверял. Но негативный опыт есть. Поэтому делаю так, чтобы точно работало во всех браузерах в любых сочетаниях

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, так вроде трансформации тут вообще не нужны, можно просто эллипсы рисовать? Или ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Qwertiy как не нужны трансформации? А повернуть эллипс Это уже transform="rotate(Angle x y)"

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а если path d a?

Comment: @Qwertiy так я так и сделал орбиты - `path` а изменение параметра `d` нужно только для анимации из одного положения фигуры в другое. Тут же три фиксированных элемента - орбиты, для каждой свой патч

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, на картинке из inkscape'а кривые безье.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, кривые Безье, а разве они не могут входить в path?

Comment: @Qwertiy наконец я понял, о чём ты спрашиваешь. Ты ожидал увидеть в формуле path координаты точек, раз я рисую по точкам. Так это узловые точки, когда рисуешь инструментом  в редакторе - `рисовать кривые Безье` и редактор автоматом пишет формулу path с кривыми Безье

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я ожидал в path увидеть `a`, а не `c`.

Answer (score 7):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mpath

Анимация в центре экрана - откройте на полную страницу

Весь фокус здесь в mpath то есть рисуем нужный контур и пишем :

```
  <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
   </animateMotion>
```

Где в xlink:href указываем путь по которому будет проходить анимация

Я нарисовал в inkscape и от туда взял пути(path) и всё а анимацию взял с MDN

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 100 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
<path id="path" d="m71.062636 139.92242c-14.55985 9.68339-7.492636 16.22044-7.492636 16.22044 10.246628 8.52181 41.9927 11.48821 62.35494 8.97865 0.37127-0.0458-0.0516-0.11729 0.31323-0.17721 6.25449-1.02743 29.07707-9.26261 20.84864-20.96068-10.1474-14.4262-62.425692-13.10521-76.024174-4.0612z" fill="none" stroke="#003f3a" stroke-width="1"/>
  
<path id="path1" d="m131.91368 174.91369c0 17.53504-8.97693 14.55208-8.97693 14.55208-15.72153-3.83816-33.551167-29.49286-40.348961-48.38095-0.126682-0.35199 0.126926-0.0176-0.0134-0.35964-2.405628-5.86406-7.386524-29.08997 6.911467-28.74452 16.016924 0.38699 42.427824 45.39799 42.427824 62.93303z" fill="none"  stroke-width="1" stroke="#003f3a"/>

<path id="path2"  d="m79.366467 174.53571c0 17.53504 8.97693 14.55208 8.97693 14.55208 15.721523-3.83816 33.551163-29.49286 40.348953-48.38095 0.12669-0.35199-0.12692-0.0176 0.0134-0.35964 2.40563-5.86406 7.38653-29.08997-6.91146-28.74452-16.01693 0.38699-42.427823 45.39799-42.427823 62.93303z" fill="none" stroke="#003f3a" stroke-width="1"/>
   

  
<path transform="translate(-120,-133)"d="m125.62053 133.7262a3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1-3.35713 3.16815 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1-3.35716-3.16815 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1 3.35716-3.16816 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1 3.35713 3.16816z" fill="#800000">
   <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
   </animateMotion>   
</path>

  <path transform="translate(-88,-140)" d="m94.059517 143.1756a3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1-3.35713 3.16815 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1-3.357159-3.16815 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1 3.357159-3.16816 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1 3.35713 3.16816z" fill="#800000">
   <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
   </animateMotion>       
  </path>
  
  <path transform="translate(-113,-184)" d="m117.87202 185.50893a3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1-3.35713 3.16815 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1-3.35716-3.16815 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1 3.35716-3.16816 3.3571483 3.1681601 0 0 1 3.35713 3.16816z" fill="#800000">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#path2"/>
   </animateMotion>      
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ой, кто-то минус поставил Нормально же сделано (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я только единственное не знаю как пустить круг отрицательно - то есть по часовой стрелке

Comment: ответил на твой вопрос по вращению шарика

Answer (score 5):

Ответ по [комментарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085654/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0/1085982#comment1867348_1085690):

> я только единственное не знаю как пустить круг отрицательно - то есть по часовой стрелке

И ещё в вопросе ТС было пожелание сделать вращение электронов неравномерным.

Эту проблему решают атрибуты анимации: [keyPoints, keyTimes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keyPoints)

```
 <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0.5;0" keyTimes="0;0.15;1" calcMode="linear">
       <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_1"/>
   </animateMotion>
```

В этом примере вращение розового шарика будет против часовой стрелки `keyPoints="1;0.5;0"`.

Синий шарик движется по часовой стрелке `keyPoints="0;0.5;1"`

`keyTimes="0;0.15;1"` - Обеспечивает неравномерность движения по времени одного цикла вращения.

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#AED75B;
 stroke-width:4;
}
.core {
fill:url(#Rg);
}

.crimson {
fill:#FF41F9;
stroke:crimson;
opacity:0.3;
stroke-width:3;
} 
.green {
fill:yellowgreen;
stroke:green;
opacity:0.3;
stroke-width:3;
}
.dodgerblue {
fill:dodgerblue;
stroke:#6177FF;
opacity:0.2;
stroke-width:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="406" height="358" viewBox="0 0 406 358">
  <defs>
  <radialGradient id="Rg"  >
   <stop stop-color="#AED75B" offset="0.25">
  <!-- Анимация смены цвета градиента -->
  <animate
    attributeName="stop-color"
 dur="4s"
 values="#AED75B;#69009D;#AED75B"
 begin="0s"
 
 repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
   </stop>
   <stop stop-color="#69009D" offset="1">
    <animate
  attributeName="stop-color"
  dur="2s"
  values="#69009D;#AED75B;#69009D"
  begin="0s"
  
  repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
  
  </radialGradient>
 </defs> 
 
 
 <path id="orbita_1" class="crimson" d="m279 29.9c24 6.8 23.5 39.1 21.8 60.5-2.1 26.4-10.5 47.3-19.3 69.7-7.3 18.7-17.4 36.3-27.8 53.5-9 14.9-18.7 29.5-29.6 43.1-10.4 12.9-21 25.9-33.8 36.5-13 10.7-27 21.5-43.1 26.6-7.7 2.4-17 5.2-24.2 1.5-10.6-5.4-17.4-18.5-19.1-30.3-4.3-29.8 4.6-60.3 14.5-88.5 9.5-26.8 19.3-42.7 31.3-62.7 12.2-20.3 25.1-40.4 41-57.9 13.2-14.6 27.3-29.1 44.5-38.6 13.3-7.4 30.1-17.1 43.6-13.3z" class="s0"/> 
       <!-- Орбита вращения -->
  <path id="orbita_2" class="green" d="m40.5 175.3c0.9-16.1 16.2-30.3 30.4-37.5 13.2-6.6 27.2-11.4 41.3-15.7 12.2-3.7 24.6-6.8 37.2-8.7 14-2.2 28.3-2.8 42.5-3.4 10.6-0.5 21.2-0.6 31.9-0.4 11.4 0.2 22.8 0.2 34.1 1.5 11.2 1.3 22.4 3.5 33.4 6.1 9.6 2.2 19.3 4.3 28.4 8 13.1 5.2 27.4 9.9 37.5 19.7 6.1 5.9 11.2 13.7 12.5 22 1.1 6.8-0.5 14.3-4.2 20.1-7.5 11.6-21.2 17.8-33.4 24.3-9.5 5.1-20 8.2-30.3 11.3-13.9 4.2-28.1 7.7-42.5 9.9-15.8 2.4-31.8 3-47.8 3.4-12 0.3-24-0.2-36-0.8-11.8-0.6-23.6-0.7-35.3-2.7-17.5-2.9-34.9-7.1-51.6-13.3C78.6 215.4 67.6 212 59.5 204.8 50.8 197 39.9 187 40.5 175.3Z" class="s0"/>
  <path id="orbita_3" class="dodgerblue"  d="m119.8 34.9c7.9-4.7 18.2-5.7 27.3-4.3 10.1 1.5 19.1 7.7 27.6 13.3 9.5 6.2 17.8 14.2 25.9 22.1 7 6.8 13.5 14.1 19.6 21.6 11.1 13.6 21.6 27.7 30.9 42.6 7.1 11.4 12.8 23.6 18.8 35.6 4.7 9.4 9.8 18.7 13.7 28.4 5.6 14.1 10.6 28.4 13.7 43.2 3 14.2 4.8 28.8 4.6 43.4-0.1 6.7-0.4 13.7-2.7 20-2.2 5.9-5.2 12.1-10.1 15.9-5.5 4.2-12.8 6.4-19.7 6.5-9.6 0-18.9-4.3-27.4-8.8-10.9-5.8-20-14.6-29.1-22.9-9.5-8.6-18.5-17.9-26.6-27.9-12.4-15.4-22.9-32.2-33.3-49-6.8-11.1-13.5-22.2-19-34-6.2-13.2-11.1-27-15.5-40.8-3.9-12-7.9-24.1-9.9-36.6-1.9-11.8-2.7-23.9-1.9-35.8 0.5-6.7 1-13.7 3.8-19.9 2.1-4.8 5-9.8 9.5-12.5z" class="s0"/>  
      <!-- Анимация вращения  электрона -1 вокруг ядра   -->
  <circle class="circ"  fill="#B873B6"  cx="0" cy="0" r="10"  > 
      <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0.5;0" keyTimes="0;0.15;1" calcMode="linear">
       <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_1"/>
   </animateMotion>    
        
   </circle>  
     <!-- Анимация вращения  электрона -2 вокруг ядра   -->
     <circle class="circ" fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="10"  > 
       <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0.5;1" keyTimes="0;0.15;1"  >
        <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_2"/>
       </animateMotion>    
    </circle>    
    <!-- Анимация вращения  электрона -3 вокруг ядра   -->
    <circle class="circ" fill="#6177FF" cx="0" cy="0" r="10"  > 
       <animateMotion dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0;0.5;1" keyTimes="0;0.20;1" >
        <mpath xlink:href="#orbita_3"/>
       </animateMotion>    
    </circle>  
        <!-- Центральное ядро -->
  <path class="core" d="m203.8 139.7c8.9-0.2 18.6 2.7 25.2 8.6 7.5 6.7 12.9 17.3 12.9 27.4-0.1 11.1-6.1 22.7-14.5 30-6.2 5.4-15.4 8.2-23.6 7.5-10.9-0.9-22.9-5.5-29.2-14.7-4.6-6.6-8.7-14.5-8.6-22.5 0.2-9.4 4.2-19.5 11-26 6.9-6.6 17.3-10 26.8-10.2zM279 29.9" class="s0"/>
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky наоборот, - по умолчанию по часовой стрелке `keyPoints="0;0.5;1"`

Comment: @MaximLensky посмотрел твой пример и понял ещё один нюанс - всё зависит от изначального направления рисования path в векторном редакторе. Другими словами в каком направлении нарисовал, то направление вращения и будет по умолчанию. А keyPoints может поменять это направление

Answer (score 2):

Пример на css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.atom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateX(66deg);
}

.atom__core {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a1005e 0%, #800080 100%);
  margin: -36px 0 0 -36px;
  transform: rotateX(-66deg);
}

.atom,
.atom__orbit,
.atom__electron {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.atom__core,
.atom__orbit,
.atom__electron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.atom__orbit {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  margin-top: -10em;
  margin-left: -10em;
  border: 1px solid #800080;
  animation: rotateOrbit 5s linear infinite;
}

.atom__electron {
  width: .9em;
  height: .9em;
  margin-top: -.45em;
  margin-left: -.45em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a1005e 0%, #800080 100%);
  left: 100%;
  animation: rotateElectron 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateOrbit {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateElectron {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

.atom__orbit--2 {
  animation-name: rotateOrbit2;
}

@keyframes rotateOrbit2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg) rotateX(-11deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(55deg) rotateX(-11deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

.atom__orbit--3 {
  animation-name: rotateOrbit3;
}

@keyframes rotateOrbit3 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(-55deg) rotateX(-11deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-55deg) rotateX(-11deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="atom">
  <div class="atom__orbit atom__orbit--1">
    <div class="atom__electron"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="atom__orbit atom__orbit--2">
    <div class="atom__electron"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="atom__orbit atom__orbit--3">
    <div class="atom__electron"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="atom__core"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ на CSS!

Answer (score 1):

Изобрел специально для этого сниппета

```js
formulanimator(document.querySelector('g'));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/strangerintheq/formulanimator/0.0.1/formulanimator.js"></script>

<svg viewbox="-10,-10,20,20" height=90vh width=90vw>
  <circle r="2"></circle>
  <g>
    <circle r="0.2" 
      data-cx="Math.cos(t*2)*9" data-cy="Math.sin(t*2)*4"></circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(45)" r="0.2" 
      data-cx="Math.cos(t*3+2)*9" data-cy="Math.sin(t*3+2)*4"></circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(-45)" r="0.2" 
      data-cx="Math.cos(t*4+4)*9" data-cy="Math.sin(t*4+4)*4"></circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(90)" r="0.2" 
      data-cx="Math.cos(t*5+5)*9" data-cy="Math.sin(t*5+5)*4"></circle>
  </g>  
  
  <g stroke-width="0.03" stroke="black" fill="none">
    <ellipse rx="9" ry="4"></ellipse>  
    <ellipse transform="rotate(45)" rx="9" ry="4"></ellipse> 
    <ellipse transform="rotate(-45)" rx="9" ry="4"></ellipse> 
    <ellipse transform="rotate(90)" rx="9" ry="4"></ellipse> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: изобрел скрипт сам? Здорово! Траектории движения хорошо бы добавить, чтобы лучше смотрелось

Comment: @Alexandr_TT у меня давно он давно назревал...